# Vue refs exist but refs[key] is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a bunch of dynamically rendered checkboxes using a v-for loop. I set the reference equal to an id specific to that checkbox. In mounted(), I print the references. Then I print reference[id] and I get undefined.

Code:

```
let id = this.$route.query[key];
console.log(id);
console.log(this.$refs);
console.log(this.$refs[id]);
```

Result:

[image: Things going wrong]

Any idea whats going on here? I know that the references exist because its in mounted and they are printing. If I try changing the reference to equal something else, it still doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: i guess this `i` in your console log states something like just now calculated. so most like the moment you acces vie key they dont exists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using refs with v-for, the component / DOM nodes are stored as an array directly to the variable name

for example

```
<list-item
v-for="item in items" 
:key="item.id"
:value="item.value"
ref="items"
/>
```

Use the refs in your component like this:

```
this.$refs.items[index]
```

Comment: Thanks. This was the answer I was looking for. I was trying to give a unique reference to each checkbox.